# Replaced bad camshaft sensor on '97 Ranger, still won't start

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, ranger, cam-position-sensor

I had an error code on my '97 Ranger that said it needed a new camshaft position sensor, but since the truck still ran fine I put off replacing it.  One night I tried to start it, and it fired up for one or two seconds then died.  The engine just clicked once when I tried to start it, and there was now an error code for "multiple cylinder misfire" in addition to the bad sensor, which I've read is a logical next thing to go wrong if your camshaft position sensor is bad.

So I got a new sensor and replaced the bad one, but it still just clicks once when you try to start it, and now shows either no OBD codes or just says "error" on my code reader.  I tried sending an erase codes message and draining the power from the electrical system (while the battery was unhooked of course) to reset the ECM, but neither did anything. Does the engine timing need to be reset by a shop? Ideas?  What am I missing?

Comment: "clicks" sounds like a bad battery to me, that or the alternator is not charging the battery. charge the battery, see if it starts now.

Comment: Can you verify your results with a different scan tool? There was another issue here recently where the code reader was displaying errors that boiled down to just a faulty scanner. Could also be an ECU issue. I'd focus on figuring out why your scanner is failing first.

Comment: Moab, thanks for the advice.  The battery was only weeks old buy I cleaned the terminals and tried jumping it, no luck.

Comment: Jason C, thanks for the advice.  My other scan tool is missing or stolen, but I will try to borrow one from a shop soon and try that also.  Thanks.

Comment: Will the engine turn over by hand?  You may have to remove the sparkplugs to check easily...

Comment: Personally the first logical thing I'd have done was check that the cab belt / chain was still intact and the cam and crank still timed up correctly.

Comment: I think it would be useful for you to mention what the exact code was

Comment: Can you help out with more description about the "clicks"? Does the engine turn over at all? I agree with @Moab that what you're describing there sounds like a starter issue. My suggestion would be to start by working that issue – if the engine doesn't crank, charge the battery to eliminate that as the problem. When you say "no luck" with jumping, what specifically happened? Crank and no start? More clicking? Wouldn't hurt to confirm that the engine can be turned over.

Comment: The exact code for the sensor was PO340, can't find the exact number of the multiple cylinder misfire code, will look next time I get home.  As far as what happens when you try to start or jump it, it doesn't turn over at all, it will click one time only.  If you try to turn the key again without removing the key, it won't click at all.  If you remove and reinsert the key you get a single click again.  I will try to manually rotate the engine when I get home Monday, I haven't done that before...still a rookie at a lot of this, but learning!

Comment: You need to solve the starting (click) issue before you can continue with diagnosis.